# Is it possible to grant a group access to a specific wiki page?

Tags: 2007, wiki, access

I have a SharePoint 2007 wiki library and want to grant all authenticated users READ access to specific pages without granting them READ access to the entire wiki library.  Is this possible with out-of-the-box capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can provide permissions on an item-level basis.  Just select the drop-down menu on the wiki page item while viewing the wiki page library and you can adjust the permissions.